# how to prevent bars from stacking, when a factor is present multiple times?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issues in preventing same factor from stacking on top of itself when plotting a barplot. Problem is that I don't know how to plot the unique values of such factor and i end up having it n times (n = times the factor is repeated) in the same plot. Here a nice example of the issue:

```
library("ggplot2")

mydata <- data.frame(var_one=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 5), var_two=rep(c(1.5, 2, 2.2, 1.8, 1.2), 5))

dev.new()
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=var_one, y=var_two)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightcoral", alpha=.8, width=.4, color="black")
```

the goal is to have only one of the multiple stacked factors. How to do it? I also tried with `geom_col`, instead of `geom_bar` but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

```
dev.new()
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=var_one, y=var_two)) +
    geom_col(fill="lightcoral", alpha=.8, width=.4, color="black")
```

This is what i need:

```
mydata_mod <- data.frame(var_one=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), var_two=c(1.5, 2, 2.2, 1.8, 1.2))

dev.new()
ggplot(mydata_mod, aes(x=var_one, y=var_two)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightcoral", alpha=.8, width=.4, color="black")
```

but the problem is the data structure that i am using is not in the format of `mydata_mod` but it is defined as `mydata` and i have to keep it that way. Ideas?

Comment: You can remove duplicated rows from var_one.


    mydata <- data.frame(var_one=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 5), var_two=rep(c(1.5, 2, 2.2, 1.8, 1.2), 5))
    
    ggplot(mydata[!duplicated(mydata$var_one),], aes(x=var_one, y=var_two)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightcoral", alpha=.8, width=.4, color="black")

Comment: @Beeflight31 i feel this will affect other variables that I need to plot, too. am i right? the table i provided is just two cols, but i have more factors that will be used in plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by using `stat_summary` or by switching to `stat="summary"` in `geom_bar` to compute the `sum` on the fly:

```r
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = var_one, y = var_two)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "bar", fun = "sum",
    fill = "lightcoral", alpha = .8, width = .4, color = "black"
  )
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = var_one, y = var_two)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "summary", fun = "sum",
    fill = "lightcoral", alpha = .8, width = .4, color = "black"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: great, this does the trick! I just wanted to add a further point, which will keep the same "magnitude" of the original data, on the y-axis. Since all the repeated values are same, i believe using `mean` instead of `sum` may be ideal.

Comment: Aw. Yeah. Of course. Missed that point. As the obs. are duplicates, in that case case another option would be to get rid of the duplicates using e.g. `dplyr::distinct(table, var_one, var_two)`. But now you know about using `stat_summary`. (:

Comment: now I do, thank you! and, also, i think I can't remove duplicates because other factors that i did not mention will be used for the plotting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to wrangle the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(var_one) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(var_two)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = var_one, y=sum)) +
  geom_col(fill="lightcoral", alpha=.8, width=.4, color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: yep, this is also interesting! plus, as i already mentioned, it would be better to use the function `mean`, instead of `sum`, to have a fair representation of the original data.